# How to send preemptive Authorization header using NSMutableURLRequest / NSURLConnection?

Tags: rest, http, cocoa

I'm unable to send a preemptive Authorization header using NSMutableURLRequest / NSURLConnection. The Authorization header is always removed before the HTTP request is sent to the server. I understand this header (among others) is restricted ([Reserved HTTP Headers](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest)), however, sending a preemptive Authorization header is allowed by [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), so I'm wondering how this can be achieved. The REST API I'm trying to use expects a preemptive header and doesn't send a 401 challenge to the client if the header is not present.

According to similar questions posted before, setting the Authorization header in a NSMutableURLRequest was possible but not anymore. You can set it, but it'll be removed.

Is there a way to force the Authorization header to be sent in the initial HTTP request without having to wait for an 401 response from the server?

Comment: You could try using a proxy to insert the header (e.g. if the credentials are always the same), or rename a header which you write in the client (so client retains control over auth credentials).

Comment: @Adrien Thanks. Can't rename/use a different header because I don't own the API. The proxy idea might work but seems overly complicated for such a simple requirement.

Comment: The proxy would rename the header from something the client would be permitted to add into whatever the API needs. If you can't change what the client sends, nor what the API will accept then it must be changed in between. That's a proxy.